# Problem with cluster installation with cloudera manager

Tags: 14.04, ssh, hadoop, cloudera-manager

I am installing **Cloudera Manager** in my system(14.04/64b).

While installing at the final step, before finish installation I got some *ERRORs* in validation as shown below,

[image]

errors in above page are,

1. ERROR 1

   **Individual hosts resolved their own hostnames correctly.**

   *Host localhost expected to have name localhost but resolved (InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()) itself to arul-pc.*
2. ERROR 2

   **The following errors were found while checking /etc/hosts...**

   - The hostname localhost is not the first match for address 127.0.0.1
     in /etc/hosts on localhost. Instead, arul-pc is the first match. The
     FQDN must be the first entry in /etc/hosts for the corresponding IP.
   - In /etc/hosts on localhost, the IP 127.0.0.1 is present multiple times. A given IP should only be listed once.

> **Note(info)**::

In my `/etc/hosts`,

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       arul-pc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

> **Note 2(my try)**::

I tried to avoid `arul-pc` from `/etc/hosts/` as,

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.0.1      arul-pc
```

after saved and Run again, Error 2 cleared, but Error 1 changed as,

**Individual hosts resolved their own hostnames correctly.**

*Host localhost failed to execute InetAddress.getLocalHost() with error: arul-pc: arul-pc. This typically means that the hostname could not be resolved.*

Answer (score 0):

The configuration in /etc/hosts that removed the warning for me was

```
#127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.13.27  cloudera2
```

localhost is commented and I only use the machine ip
the machine hostname is also cloudera2

if you don't want to expose your machine, then use only

```
127.0.0.1  cloudera2
```